# Calculation based Fixed LOD expression

Tags: tableau-api, bi-tool

I am trying to Sums the Spend based on CampaignName, campaign start date and Today's Date( today Date - 1).

Below is the Calculation Field created by me

```
{FIXED [CampaignName] : SUM({ FIXED
[CampaignName],[Date]>=[CampaignStartDate] AND [Date] <= [Today Date]: SUM([Spend])})}
```

But Calculation is show sum of all spend values in campaignName and not working for the date range that is added in the calculation field `"[Date]>=[CampaignStartDate] AND [Date] <= [Today Date]"`.

Please Help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
{FIXED [CampaignName] : 
SUM(If [Date]>=[CampaignStartDate] AND [Date] <= [Today Date]
Then [Spend]
END)}
```